# After successful payment I want to show status Payment complete

Tags: payment, magento2.3.2

After successful payment, I want to display order status as `payment complete` instead of `processing` in Magento 2.3.2., How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here.

1. Programmatically you can change the status of the Order Whatever you want to set.
2. Programmatically you can generate the Invoice and Shipment for the order, this will also set the status as "Completed"